# Populate table with INSERT INTO table_name (table_columns) VALUES ((SELECT()), (SELECT()), (SELECT()))

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, sql-insert

I have the following ugly table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEE7H.png)

With an after insertion trigger I want to call the following procedure. As you can see that procedure populates the tables proc_sub_start, proc_sub_end and proc_sub_item with the non null values of the start_end_date table (ugly table). Then with multiple selects I want to populate the at once the final_table with the values of those tables. Then empty those tables and repeat the same process at each insertion. Below is my procedure:

```
delimiter $
create procedure add_to_final_arr()
     begin
     insert into proc_sub_start (proc_sub_id_start, proc_sub_start_date)
     select sub_id_start, sub_start_date from start_end_date where sub_id_start is not null and sub_start_date is not null;
     insert into proc_sub_end (proc_sub_id_end, proc_sub_end_date)
     select sub_id_end, sub_end_date from start_end_date where sub_id_end is not null and sub_end_date is not null;
     insert into proc_sub_item (proc_item)
     select distinct(sub_item) from start_end_date where sub_item is not null;
     insert into final_table (start_sub_id, start_sub_date, end_sub_date, sub_item)
     values ((select proc_sub_id_start from proc_sub_start),(select proc_sub_start_date from proc_sub_start) ,(select proc_sub_end_date from proc_sub_end), (select proc_item from proc_sub_item));
     delete from proc_sub_start;
     delete from proc_sub_end;
     delete from proc_sub_item;
     end;
     $
```

The problem is I get the following error when I am trying to call the procedure:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Below you can see the description of the tables that will do the populating of the final_table and the final_table description:

[Description of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3aTD.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
MariaDB [demo]> select * from start_end_date;
```

| sub_id_start | sub_start_date | sub_id_end | sub_end_date | sub_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | NULL | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |
| 2804 | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | NULL | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-05-30 16:27:59 | 2804 | 2021-06-30 16:26:57 | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | NULL | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |
| NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |
| 2806 | 2021-05-30 18:30:52 | NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | 2806 | 2022-08-31 18:30:52 | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |

```
8 rows in set (0.000 sec)

 

MariaDB [demo]>  select max(sub_id_start) sub_id_start, max(sub_start_date) sub_start_date, max(sub_id_end) sub_id_end, max(sub_end_date) sub_end_date, max(sub_item) sub_item from start_end_date;select max(sub_id_start) sub_id_start, max(sub_start_date) sub_start_date, max(sub_id_end) sub_id_end, max(sub_end_date) sub_end_date, max(sub_item) sub_item from start_end_date;

+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+

| sub_id_start | sub_start_date      | sub_id_end | sub_end_date        | sub_item                            |

+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+

|         2806 | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 |       2806 | 2022-08-31 18:30:52 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |

+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [demo]> select max(sub_id_start) sub_id_start, sub_start_date, max(sub_id_end) sub_id_end, sub_end_date, max(sub_item) sub_item

    -> from start_end_date

    -> group by sub_start_date, sub_end_date;

+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+

| sub_id_start | sub_start_date      | sub_id_end | sub_end_date        | sub_item                            |

+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+

|         2804 | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 |       NULL | 2021-05-30 16:26:57 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |

|         NULL | 2021-05-30 16:27:59 |       2804 | 2021-06-30 16:26:57 | NULL                                |

|         2806 | 2021-05-30 18:30:52 |       NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | NULL                                |

|         NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 |       NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 | 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera |

|         NULL | 2021-05-30 18:30:53 |       2806 | 2022-08-31 18:30:52 | NULL                                |

+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do not post pictures - post formatted text. Do not post DESC - post SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

Comment: *As you can see that procedure populates the tables proc_sub_start, proc_sub_end and proc_sub_item with the non null values of the start_end_date table (ugly table).* Do you want to say that `proc_sub_start` defines a row, and if a lot of rows have the same `proc_sub_start` value then they're copies (maybe, partial due to some column value lost and replaced with NULL)?

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your suggestions.  I am not sure if I underastand your question, but I ll try to explain what I want to do better. The initial table (Ugly table) is a table that everytime an item has been bought 4 rows will be inserted there. As you can see there are some non null values. Everytime 4 new rows will be inserted I want to call that procedure above and populate the right tables like proce_sub_start with the right non null values. Then these values will be inserted to final_table, I will empty the tables and the process will be repeated on every insertion.

Comment: *everytime an item has been bought 4 rows will be inserted there.* Now imagine that 3 diffrerent goods were bought at the same second, and you have 12 well-mixed rows related to these 3 goods. Do you have some attribute which allows to say "these 4 rows are a group" unambiguously?

Comment: @Akina In the situation that I am dealing with there would be no such problem. Imagine that every 4 rows in the start_end_date are a product and nothing is mixed. The problem is on how to get these values from the tables that I populate in the procedure and store them to the final_table. So everytime 4 rows will be added at the start_end_date table, 1 row will be added at the final_table.

Comment: The answer with SELECT added. It gives 1 row from all 4 rows - you may save it into `final_table`.

Comment: Your UPDATE data looks illogically. I cannot understand how start datetime may be more that 1 minute past the end datetime.

Comment: @Akina The correct sub_start_date is the one next to sub_id_start and the correct sub_end_date is next to the sub_id_end (2804, 2806)

Comment: *The correct sub_start_date is the one next to sub_id_start* Define ORDER BY expression which provides shown rows ordering and allows the term "next to" to exist. Physical relative rows posession is not an option.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your answers and your help. Due to the nature of the first table (start_end_date) is why I need the procedure that I am trying to code and it doesn't seem there is another way to populate the final_table with the correct data. If you have another suggestion of how to insert into a table with multiple selects, I would be more than glad to hear it. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: *If you have another suggestion* From the same begining I try to tell that you are the only who can **and who must** to formulate the criteria which allows, looking at 2 rows, unambiguously say that they're from the same rows group or from different rows groups. Until such criteria exists the task cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine that every 4 rows in the start_end_date are a product and nothing is mixed. The problem is on how to get these values from the tables that I populate in the procedure and store them to the final_table. So everytime 4 rows will be added at the start_end_date table, 1 row will be added at the final_table.

Assuming that `start_end_date` means "sub_start_date and sub_end_date values pair":

```sql
SELECT MAX(sub_id_start) sub_id_start,
       sub_start_date,
       MAX(sub_id_end) sub_id_start,
       sub_end_date,
       MAX(sub_item) sub_item
FROM ugly_table
GROUP BY sub_start_date, sub_end_date
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It gave the idea to use the following query: select max(sub_id_start) sub_id_start, max(sub_start_date) sub_start_date, max(sub_id_end) sub_id_end, max(sub_end_date) sub_end_date, max(sub_item) sub_item from start_end_date; Unfortunately that only works if I have only 4 rows in the start_end_date(ugly). What if I have 8 not mixed rows?

Comment: @CostasMal *What if I have 8 not mixed rows?* How may rows are produced by both my and your queries from these 8 rows?

Comment: From your query 5 rows are produced and from mine 1

Comment: Please post these 8 rows (as formatted table, not a picture) into the question as an update. Also mark the groups of 4 rows each and explain why them are the groups.

Comment: As you can see another 1-Tier Ransomware Security - 1 tera has been bought and it has sub_id = 2806